# What is the meaning of client coordinates in SetWindowPos

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

The documentation for [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says the following for the X and Y parameters:

> X [in]
>
> Type: int
>
> The new position of the left side of the window, in client coordinates.
>
> Y [in]
>
> Type: int
>
> The new position of the top of the window, in client coordinates.

By "client coordinates", does it mean that the parameters specify the position of the **client area** of the window, or that they specify the position of the window (not the client area) relative to the parent window's client area? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your second proposition: The position of the window in its parent's client area.

Comment: will it be equal to screen coordinates for a top level window, i.e. a window which have Desktop as its parent, essentially the main window of most applications we use?

Comment: Yes, it's screen co-ordinates for a top level window.